# Json_decode throws "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to use the simple weather API, but somehow it doesn't recognize it as an object whatever I do. This is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.amdoren.com/api/weather.php?api_key=za8LEJ8F9mcHK8SvLxdM98rM9mNFjW&lat=40.7127837&lon=-74.0059413";
$curl = curl_init($url);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$jsonobj = json_decode($curl_response);
$msg = "Temperature in ".$city."will be: ". $jsonobj->forecast->max_c;
```

and this is the data I'm trying to reach with `$jsonojb->forecast->max_c`:

```
{
 "error" : 0,
 "error_message" : "-",
 "forecast":[ 
 {"date":"2016-12-02",
 "avg_c":8,
 "min_c":5,
 "max_c":11,
 "avg_f":46,
 "min_f":41,
 "max_f":52,
  (...)
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 2):

forecast is an array, so you have to use like this:

```
$forecast = $jsonobj->forecast;
$forecast[0]->max_c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this code:

```
$url = "https://www.amdoren.com/api/weather.php?api_key=za8LEJ8F9mcHK8SvLxdM98rM9mNFjW&lat=40.7127837&lon=-74.0059413";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$jsonobj = json_decode($curl_response);

$msg = "Temperature in ". $city . " will be: ". $jsonobj->forecast[0]->max_c;
echo $msg;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The "forecast" is an array, you have to add [0] to get the first one and then you will be able to get your "max_c".

Also, your API does not give you the city. You would have to use the Google Geocoding API to convert the lon,lat into a City Name.

```
   $api_key = "za8LEJ8F9mcHK8SvLxdM98rM9mNFjW";

    $lon = -74.0059413;
    $lat = 40.7127837;


    $url = "https://www.amdoren.com/api/weather.php?api_key=".$api_key."&lat=".$lat."&lon=".$lon."";


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


    $max_c = $response['forecast'][0]['max_c'];

    // Your API doesn't return the city name.
    $city = "City Name"; 
    $msg = "Temperature in ".$city."will be: ". $max_c;
    echo $msg;
```

To get your City Name, here's the function you can use. You will need to replace the API KEY.

```
// Geocode
function geocode($lat,$lon){

   $details_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lon."&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

   // If Status Code is ZERO_RESULTS, OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, REQUEST_DENIED or INVALID_REQUEST
   if ($response['status'] != 'OK') {
    return null;
   }

   $formatted_address = $response['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
   $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];

    $longitude = $geometry['location']['lat'];
    $latitude = $geometry['location']['lng'];

    $array = array(
        'lat' => $geometry['location']['lng'],
        'lon' => $geometry['location']['lat'],
        'location_type' => $geometry['location_type'],
        'formatted_address' => $formatted_address
    );

    return $array;

}
```

Comment: Your code is the only that solves the problem in the sense that it doesn't throw an error anymore but it still doesn't show anything and it's not about the city name 'cause I already took care of that but forgot to mention (it's a combo box where you can only choose like three cities anyway). So it's just like The temperature in New York will be: - and that's it.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie When I tried with your API Key, it was giving me a limit exceeded error. That could be the problem. Try doing print_r($response) and see if there is an error.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie just tried again, your API Key is the issue. Look here: http://d.tanios.ca/sh/ (same code), it gives a 0 when using your key.

Comment: I tried it with the new api key and still throws the error (the limit exceeded error didn't turn up until I posted the question here). My current problem is that it doesn't throw the error (with the new api key), it just doesn't show the $response at all. Even with the old api key, it doesn't give a 0, it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: I can try to help you on Slack or Hangouts, not sure how to share my contact. Let me know!